# Scala Playframework: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm extremely new to the Play framework. I'm working from the Play for Scala book. Its a little outdated since Play has moved on. I'm trying to get @Messages to work in one of my views but having trouble doing so and I'm getting the error in the title bar/in the image I posted.[image]

This is the view that I'm trying to display.

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit lang: Lang) @()(implicit Messages: Messages).
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>@title</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
         href='@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/bootstrap.css")'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
      href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="screenshot">
         <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
               <div class="container">
                  <a class="brand" href="@routes.HomeController.index()">
                  @Messages("application.name") <!--this is the error I get in the title-->
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="container">
            @content
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have 2 controllers both pretty much do the same thing.
Here is the first.

```
package controllers
import play.api.mvc.{Action,Controller}
import models.Product
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.i18n._

class Products @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {
  def list = Action { implicit request =>
    val products = Product.findAll
    Ok(views.html.products.list(products))
  }
}
```

Here is the second:

```
package controllers
import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject() extends Controller {
  def index = Action { implicit request =>
    Redirect(routes.Products.list())
  }
}
```

Here is the routes

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaRouting
# ~~~~

# An example controller showing a sample home page
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)

GET /products controllers.Products.list
```

Here is the messages file:

```
    # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaI18N

application.name = Product catalog
```

I'm really stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change first line of view like this: `@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit lang: Lang, messages: Messages).` Implicit parameters must all go in one parameter list, and this list must be the last one.

Comment: the compiler doesn't provide a fix. I just checked it. insan-e, your solution worked. thank you so much for your help